# Having a PHP file send form data to a file named after one of the form data pieces

Tags: php, filenames

The PHP code I have currently sends the data that is posted in my form to a file called newData.html. I would like it to send the data to a file that is named the same as the product name in the data.

For example, I have a product called the NS-4000. I enter the product's name in the product name blank on my form and submit the form. I want for a file named, NS-4000.html to be created with the other data pieces I have going there. In this case, I would have the name of the project lead, a description of the product and the names of the team members. This is the PHP I have so far:

```
<?php
    $Name = $_POST['Name'];
    $PLname= $_POST['PLname'];
    $Team_members= $_POST['Team_members'];
    $Description= $_POST['Description'];

    $html = <<<HEREDOC
         Product Name: $Name <br>
         Project Lead: $PLname <br>
         Team Members: $Team_members <br> <br>
         Description: $Description
    HEREDOC;
    file_put_contents('newPage.html', $html);

    header('location: newPage.html');
    exit;
```

How would I go about having my PHP code create a file with the same name as the product name in the form?

Comment: Hint: use `$Name` to construct the filename of the file which will contain your data.

Comment: Thanks! Dunno why I didn't figure that out...

Comment: You may want to make use of `strtolower` for your naming convention, should the name start with a capital letter; e.g. John.

Comment: Saving with lowercase convention `$fp = fopen(strtolower($Name) . ".html", 'w');` **or** `$fp = fopen(strtolower($Name) . 'w');` thought you might need it, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) to create a file.  Using "w" as the second parameter allows you to write to create a new file if it doesn't exist.  After that you can add contents using [fwrite()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php).  I borrowed this code from the [fwrite()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) page and modified for your situation.

```
<?php
$fp = fopen($Name, 'w');
fwrite($fp, $html);
fclose($fp);

// the content of $Name is now $html
?>
```

Comment: `file_put_contents()` that the OP is using in the example is a shortcut method for performing all the steps listed in your answer.

Comment: @Brian Glaz - Very cool, I actually hadn't seen that used yet, thanks!

Comment: Note that the main reason to use fopen()/fwrite() is to write data in chunk to lower memory usage. Useful when writing big files.